# Machine Learning DAG of dockerized algorithm, Luigi / Airflow / Celery

Tags: docker, celery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, luigi

I am building a deep learning pipeline that can be represented as a directed acyclic graph. I created simplified representation of the graph -> [Algorithm DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl1Km.jpg). Each node is a docker container, running a different ML/DL algorithm. I got each node to work by itself but now I am trying to get everything to run together. So far my approach has been using Rabbit MQ to communicate between the different containers. It works if I send images one by one and wait for the output, however on the longer term the first node will receive a continuous stream of images.

I have been looking into various libraries and frameworks, such as Luigi, Celery and Airflow but I am still hesitant to which one would be the best for my problem. The algorithms are subject to change and I would like a system that dynamically allocates resources (including GPU). Eg, maybe the v1 of my pipeline will run A-C and B at the same speed but the v2 will have B running twice as fast, in which case I would my system to adjust to the change automatically.

I have read a bit on the topic:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/lzAqI1D9wsg
and I am open to use something else than docker as long as I have separate environments for each of my nodes.

Answer (score 1):

To run Docker containers from Airflow, use the KubernetesPodOperator or DockerOperator.

Using the KubernetesPodOperator (from the [Cloud Composer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator)):

```
# Only name, namespace, image, and task_id are required to create a
# KubernetesPodOperator. In Cloud Composer, currently the operator defaults
# to using the config file found at `/home/airflow/composer_kube_config if
# no `config_file` parameter is specified. By default it will contain the
# credentials for Cloud Composer's Google Kubernetes Engine cluster that is
# created upon environment creation.
kubernetes_min_pod = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
    # The ID specified for the task.
    task_id='pod-ex-minimum',
    # Name of task you want to run, used to generate Pod ID.
    name='pod-ex-minimum',
    # Entrypoint of the container, if not specified the Docker container's
    # entrypoint is used. The cmds parameter is templated.
    cmds=['echo'],
    # The namespace to run within Kubernetes, default namespace is
    # `default`. There is the potential for the resource starvation of
    # Airflow workers and scheduler within the Cloud Composer environment,
    # the recommended solution is to increase the amount of nodes in order
    # to satisfy the computing requirements. Alternatively, launching pods
    # into a custom namespace will stop fighting over resources.
    namespace='default',
    # Docker image specified. Defaults to hub.docker.com, but any fully
    # qualified URLs will point to a custom repository. Supports private
    # gcr.io images if the Composer Environment is under the same
    # project-id as the gcr.io images.
    image='gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/ubuntu_16_0_4')
```

That said, if you aren't tied to Airflow and each node is a Docker container, you may want to use a cloud-native workflow runner like [Argo](https://github.com/argoproj/argo/blob/master/demo.md).